# How to get the sizes of selected rows in tables of a mysql database?

Tags: mysql

We have a database table having data from different customers.

We would like to know what percent of table size (in bytes) is contributed to each customer so that we can charge customer based on database size they are using? In another words, is there a way to get the size of a subset of a table?

By the way, I am aware of how to get total size of the table in bytes from the schema but that's not the question.

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean `num_rows`?

Comment: No. size of table in bytes, I have updated the question to reflect this. Thanks

Comment: I'm having trouble why you'd want it this way. Should the data of different companies not be seperates becasue security?

Comment: It might be an option to give each company tyheir own table.

Comment: @Martijn that's a different topic for discussion but for now, I like to know if there is a way in this situation

Comment: I would probably create a temporary table with only that customers data and then run a query for the total size of that table and compare it to the total size of original table or database.

Answer (score -1):

Why not to create one database for each customers to avoid multi-tenancy.If so You can now make a query to know the size of each database as illustrated in query below.

```
SELECT table_schema as 'Database Name', 
    sum( data_length + index_length ) as 'Size in Bytes',       
    round((sum(data_length + index_length) / 1024 / 1024), 4) as 'Size in MB'
    FROM     information_schema.TABLES
    GROUP BY table_schema;
```

Comment: Why don't you just stick to the question - I clearly said that I know how to take table size so all you are doing is wasting time on giving answer which I already know.